# How i can make this User Interface?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

[image]

Any help in this UI will be beneficial for me.

Comment: This is achieved through using A RecyclerView, with a GridLayoutManager, a FloatingActionButton, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout with a Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plaid is an open source showcase app, created by Nick Butcher from the Android team at Google.

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid) and the layout file for that specific screen is available [here](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_home.xml).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above: "This is achieved through using A RecyclerView, with a GridLayoutManager, a FloatingActionButton, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout with a Toolbar." This doesn't match to a T that Plaid app, but it has the same underlying layout concept.

Here is a quick sample activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.divshark.griddemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

row_holder.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_grid_item"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="144dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#77000000"
        tools:text="Item One"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        List<Item> mItems = getItems();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new DemoAdapter(mItems));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems (){
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(16);
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
            items.add(new Item("Item "+ i, R.drawable.sample) );
        }

        return items;
    }


    public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoAdapter.RowHolder>{
        List<Item>items;

        public DemoAdapter(List<Item>items){
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_holder, parent, false);
            return new RowHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RowHolder holder, int position) {

            Item item = items.get(position);
            holder.mImageView.setImageResource(item.imageResource);
            holder.mTextView.setText(item.text);
        }

        class RowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            ImageView mImageView;
            AppCompatTextView mTextView;

            public RowHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_grid_item);
                mTextView = (AppCompatTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item {
        public String text;
        public int imageResource;
        public Item(String text, int imageResource){
            this.text = text;
            this.imageResource = imageResource;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck and Happy Coding!